# Contradiction in GPL Licensing FAQ

Tags: customization

The Blender FAQ page (https://www.blender.org/support/faq/) answers these two questions:

> *Can my organization use Blender **internally** without giving up our valuable changes to our competitors?*
>   Yes. The GNU GPL does allow your organization to use a modified version of Blender internally **without offering the source-code** as long as you do not distribute it outside your company or organization.
>
> *Can I change Blender and give it to my **co-workers or employees**?*
>   Yes, but if you make modifications you must comply with the GPL and **if they request the source code you have to distribute that to them** as well. You can charge for the version of blender you give to your friends even, but it must be licensed under the GPL, and you may not charge an unreasonable fee for the source code.

**Don't these two answers contradict them selves?**

Example:
**Our** developers modify Blender and hand it to **our** production team to do some work for the company.
Individuals from **our** production team then may then **ask for source code** and are **allowed to distribute it** (under GPL)??

That would definitely be **in contradiction** with the claim that we **can** "*use a modified version of Blender internally **without** offering the source-code as long as you do not distribute it outside your company*".

Or am I getting this wrong?

(I apologize if this question does not belong here, but I could not find other place to post it.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Blender, but about interpretting the consequences of GPL.

Comment: OK, I'm beginning grasp the idea behind these statements. The way to handle this would be to prevent the modified version of leaving the company. Employees may get the source code upon request but should not be allowed to take any of it out of the company as it contains proprietary information (e.g. algorithms, know-how = "valuable changes"). Such things are usually regulated by company rules/contracts/NDAs.

Comment: @zeffi - Actually, this is a question about Blender FAQ which interpret GPL. If you know where else I could post it so the Blender FAQ would be corrected/ammended/explained, please do let me know.

Comment: This site is about providing support for the use of Blender as a tool, but you are looking to understand how the GPL works --that FAQ should not be considered legally binding advice (nor are the answers you may receive here). Consult perhaps [Software Feedome - Compliance Guide](https://www.softwarefreedom.org/resources/2008/compliance-guide.html) and a copyright lawyer specializing in OpenSource / GPL.   --- it's not that we don't want to help you but this question is way beyond the scope of BSE.

Comment: This question might be on-topic at the [Law SE](http://law.stackexchange.com/) or the [Open source SE](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/) sites.

Answer (score 2):

> Can my organization use Blender internally without giving up our valuable changes to our competitors?

The question starts with *Can..?* and indeed it's possible. All your coworkers and people who come in contact would have to **willingly** not distribute it any further and to your competitors.

If anyone decides that he wants the source code and he wants to either build upon it or further distribute it (even to your competition), he has all the rights to do it, because the software is licenced GPL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes GPL works that way. If the users requests for the code they must be made available by the license. It's the GPL license that gave blender the developmental edge. Of cos companies may look at it in a "20th century" business model point of view and think that it would be a bad idea to give out your source code.

Then again, if you are truly creative that fear should not exist. I think blender is the pinnacle of how opensource software can change the way people work in a very radical way ... "made by artist, for the artist" indeed.

Comment: OK, but then the answer to the first FAQ question should be modified because it is not complete.
Allowing employess to distribute source code outside the company is exactly "giving up our valuable changes to our competitors".

Comment: I don't think Blender has any developmental edge as it has only a handful of developers compared to commercial projects.

Comment: If you have used commercial software and paid for it's full price, you will soon realised how phenomenal blender is. 3dsmax for the past 10 year hasn't changed much... it's interface is old and it's so slow to install and load. 3dsmax still crash on exit, it does the same thing 5 years ago and still does it today. Sure they have added tools which doesn't improve workflow, I really think the difference on blender is that it's opensource ... anyone who is willing to put in time an help out with coding can do so.

Comment: I use commercial and also I use Blender. I wouldn't call Blender "phenomenal". It has it's own strengths but also not so few weaknesses. I understand that for a hobbyist it is great tool, but for a professional to whom time=money are commercial solutions like maya, houdini, zbrush and others well worth the price. You can surely make the same quality art with Blender, but it requires much more effort and usually workarounds.

Comment: Strangely I find blender more effective as a professional tool. Anyway each to his own. Some of my client prefers my blender work over my 3dsmax.